# C# - How to write string metadata to jpeg file?

Tags: c#, bitmap, metadata, jpeg, exif

I have an application that successfully reads and writes some EXIF data to jpg files. However, if the specific metadata field comes "as string", I cannot write it.

I'm probably missing some important conversion to be able to write the string properly.

For instance, some fields in the metadata are "rational" numbers. They come as `ulong` values, which should be converted to bytes, then split in half, and each half should be converted in a number, like this:

```
public Rational(UInt64 ulongFromEXIF)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ulongFromEXIF); //the UInt64 has 8 bytes
    Numerator = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.Take(4).ToArray(), 0); //first four bytes = numerator
    Denominator = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4); //last four bytes = denominator
}
```

Later I can create a new number, and use the reverse logic to create a `ulong` and I can save it successfully to the file.

But if the value from the exif query comes as string, I cannot write another value to the file.

This is how I read and write data successfully for rational numbers:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; //from reference PresentationCore, must also use WindowsBase reference

/////////////


        string imagePath = @"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx.JPG";

        //Queries to get image metadata 
        string AltQuery = "/app1/{ushort=0}/{ushort=34853}/{ushort=6}"; //query for photo altitude

        //reading
        FileInfo imageFile = new FileInfo(imagePath);  
        FileStream stream = imageFile.OpenRead();      
        BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
        BitmapMetadata metadata = (BitmapMetadata)bitmapFrame.Metadata; 

        if (metadata.ContainsQuery(AltQuery))
        {
            ulong altValue = (ulong)metadata.GetQuery(AltQuery);
            //process this as a rational like the above
        }
        stream.Close();


        //writing
        ulong newValue = someValueTransformedToUlongProperly;

        FileInfo imageFile = new FileInfo(imagePath);
        FileStream stream = imageFile.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
        InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter metadataWriter = bitmapFrame.CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter();

        metadataWriter.SetQuery(AltQuery , newValue);

        if (!metadataWriter.TrySave())
        {
            stream.Close();
            throw new IOException("Failed");
        }

        stream.Close();
```

Now, I cannot do the same for a Time Taken query, for instance, where the value from GetQuery comes "as string". How can I write a new date-time to this exif property? Other string properties also have the same problem.

A few of them, though, which have length 1, are written without a problem.

Comment: I doubt your approach: both `GetQuery()` and [`SetQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.setquery) return/expect `object`, not `string`. And `ulong` is surely cast to an object, too. Furthermore [tag 36867 **is** a string, because it only consists of ASCII bytes](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif/datetimeoriginal.html) - don't expect it to be some DateTime object. Also: rename `altValue` to `oldValue`, because [_alt_ has a meaning in English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alt#Adjective).

Comment: So, it's not a string, but it's a string.... cool. `GetQuery` returns objects that have types, `ulong` for rational numbers, `string` for strings and other types. `SetQuery` accepts the proper types, it accepts `ulong` successfully, as said in the question. It also accepts strings for some properties, not for others. Basic c# stuff. `Alt` goes for `Altitude`, that's in the dictionary, and that's the actual meaning of that Exif property. I'm aware that "time taken" is a string, that's exactly the point of the question, what to do when exif properties are strings.

Comment: I'm here for _Exif_ knowledge, not _C#_ or `.Imaging`. Data wise textual content is (with rare exceptions) always an array of (8 bit) chars=bytes - in this case exactly 20, including the last character to be `\0` ([docs 4.5.6 F, semantic page 47; explaining data type ASCII in 4.6.2, semantic page 24](https://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-X008-Translation-2019-E.pdf)). Try handing over an array, when `string` fails for reasons unknown to both of us. Or your string **length** is improper so far.